# Regex line after string

Tags: c#, regex

I want to extract views from the youtube video link.

```
string youtubelink = richTextBox1.Text;
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(youtubelink);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string data = reader.ReadToEnd();
Regex views = new Regex("watch-view-count\">" + @"\d+\s\d+");
Match v = views.Match(data);
richTextBox1.Text = Regex.Replace(v.ToString(),"watch-view-count\">", "");
```

But my problem is that "@"\d+\s\d+");" for example when the video have more views they won't show because this code shows up only xxx xxx views(same works in opposite way, if i will add one more line and the video will have less views they also won't show up) Is there any trick for regex to prevent that? Thanks.

Comment: I strongly recommend to _not_ use screen scraping but instead [use the YouTube API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24347078/retrieving-individual-videos-view-count-youtube-api-v3-0-javascript).

Comment: +1 to Uwe's suggestion and regardless, I would avoid regex with HTML and use an HTML parser such as the [HTML Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
(\d+\s)*\d+
```

In your code it would be

```
Regex views = new Regex("watch-view-count\">" + @"(\d+\s)*\d+");
```

Encapsulating the expression `\d+\s` into brackets makes it possible to specify how many times may that group appear in line. And it's sure, that a video has at least `\d+` views.