# Youtube api v3 getVideoData() list functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I used *player.getVideoData().title* to get the title of the current video, but what to use to get views?

please javascript only :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Video.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#try-it) or read the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24347078/retrieving-individual-videos-view-count-youtube-api-v3-0-javascript) about that topic.

Comment: I don't get the views snippet :(

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, made a new API request on videoId :

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id="+videoID+"&key=APIKEY


viewsCount = data.items[0].statistics.viewCount;
```